# Unable to pass an arraylist double from one activity to the other

Tags: java, android

Im new to Android development. I want to take a user input as a double value and then pass it to the next activity, and then sum it with another value, but I am having trouble passing it. 
When passing this double array called winning onto activity 2, I recieve an error. The error is: Incompatible types.
Required: java.util.ArrayList  Found: double[]

```
Activity 1
public void btnAdd_OnClick(View v)
 {
    {
        if (txtWinnings.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            displayToast("Please enter an amount");
        }else{
            double winning = 
  Double.parseDouble(txtWinnings.getText().toString());
            if(winning > 0) {
                winnings.add(winning);
                txtWinnings.setText("");
                txtWinnings.setHint("You have added " + (winnings.size()) + 
   " tournament winnings");
            } else {
                displayToast("You must enter an amount more than 0");
            }
        }
    }
   }

public void btnClear_OnClick(View v)
{
    if(winnings.size() < 0)
    {
        displayToast("You have no winnings to clear");
    }else {
        winnings.clear();
        displayToast("Cleared");
    }
 }

  public void btnSummary_OnClick(View v)
  {
      {
        if(winnings.size() > 0)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SummaryActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("winnings", winnings);
            startActivity(i);
        }else{
            displayToast("You must enter at least one amount of winnings");
        }
    }
  }
   public void displayToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }

Activity 2
public class SummaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Double> winnings = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_summary);
    setTitle("Summary");
    TextView lblTournaments = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAverage);
    TextView lblTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotal);
    TextView lblMax = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMax);
    TextView lblMin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMin);
    TextView lblAverage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAverage);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    winnings = i.getDoubleArrayExtra("winnings");

}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`winnings` is a `ArrayList<Double>`. You cannot assign it a `double[]` as you do at this line :

```
winnings = i.getDoubleArrayExtra("winnings");
```

You can convert the `double[]` to a `List<Double>` like this :

```
List<Double> winnings = Arrays.stream(i.getDoubleArrayExtra("winnings"))
    .mapToObj(d-> d)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using streams for that is a bit overkill but learning streams is worth it.

**EDIT** :

`Stream` might not be available (see comments). Without `Stream`, you can manually empty the `winnings` collection then iterate on the array to fill it again :

```
double[] array = i.getDoubleArrayExtra("winnings");
winnings.clear();
for(double winning : array) {
  winnings.add(winning);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't streams require API level 24 on Android though (or a 3rd party library)?

Comment: @Michael I don't make Android apps so I can't answer that. I will update the answer to show a more old-school way which works with Java 7.